# Audio doesn't work on Windows XP guest (WS 7.0)

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, audio, vmware

I can't get audio to work with on a Windows XP guest running on VMware Workstation 7.0 and Ubuntu 9.10 host.

Windows fails to produce any audio output and the Windows device manager says the Multimedia Audio Controller is not working properly.

Audio is working fine in the host OS.

When I open Multimedia Audio Controller properties it says:

> Device status: The drivers for this device are not installed (Code 28)

If I try to reinstall the driver I get the following error message:

> Cannot Install this Hardware
>
> There was a problem installing this hardware: Multimedia Audio Controller
>
> An Error occurred during the installation of the device
>   Driver is not intended for this platform

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Comment: Have you tried VirtualBox? I've found it to be much more stable and easy to use for desktop usage. I believe the package is in the ubuntu repo's (sudo apt-get install virtualbox), and for my Linux Mint 8 install it runs the audio just fine after the VirtualBox Guest Additions package was installed on the XP machine.

Answer (score 0):

Five days and no answer? I think you should give VirtualBox a try instead. Like I said in my comment, it worked for me. VB just unchecked the *Enable Audio* option on restart, so I had to go and re-check it after installing the guest additions.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this VMWare page](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws7/doc/releasenotes_ws7.html) WS 7 supports Ubuntu 9.04 as host but doesn't mention 9.10. Now that may have changed with minor updates but 7 is pretty old and with this type of software I would have to think about upgrading. Both v8 and v9 have worthwhile improvements and support for newer host OSs.

I used to run both WS 8 and WS 9 on Ubuntu & Kubuntu 9, 10 & 11 with XP guests without any problems.

Or try VirtualBox of course...